# JavaScript document.createElement not showing any results

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to help a friend with making his website school project, but I ran into a problem. It was meant to have 3 text boxes with a button that can add more text boxes, I tried with `document.write` but it overwrites the whole page so I looked it up and I found out about `document.createElement`, which doesn't seem to work as well.

I don't know if anything in my code is incorrect.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .input {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }

            .input .submit {
                float: left;
            }
            .add {
                margin-left: 100px;
                margin-top: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            .gen {
                float: right;
                margin-right: 100px;
                width: 400px;
                height: 50px;
                font-size: 25px;
            }

            .output {
                position: fixed;
                margin-top: 100px;
                float: right;
                margin-left: 400px;
            }

        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                 var input = document.createElement("<p>Hello</p>");
                 var container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");


            container.appendChild(input);


        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form class="buttons">
        <input type="text" class="input">
        <input type="submit" class="submit">
        <br>

        <input type="text" class="input">
        <input type="submit" class="submit">
        <input type="button" class="gen" value="Click to generate a random word">
        <input type="text" class="output">
        <br>

        <input type="text" class="input">
        <input type="submit" class="submit">
        <br>


        </form>

        <input type="button" class="add" value="+" >

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `container` is an array... ?

Comment: FYI `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">` can be written as just `<script>`. The `language` and `type` attributes default to JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing incorrect parameters to `document.createElement` - Documentation for this method can be found here: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

`document.createElement` accepts a tag name, but the other properties you have to add on through object manipulation.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "Hello";
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Secondly you are using `var container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")` which is incorrect as well. You're trying to get the container element but asking for it to get a list of element**s** with the class name of "buttons". This returns an array and requires you to select the first option that's returned e.g. `container[0].appendChild`

In truth you should be using an ID instead of a class name. ID's are meant to be unique so that singular elements can be easily found within a document, class names are meant to be used to alter multiple elements. Given your situation though, you should alter your initial query so that it just returns the singular element using `document.querySelector(".buttons")`

```
var container = document.querySelector(".buttons");
```

All Together:

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = "Hello";

var container = document.querySelector(".buttons");
container.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<form class="buttons">

  

</form>
```

A word of advice: judging from the code you've presented here you may not know the language well enough to assist in teaching it to others. That's not saying you don't have the aptitude or the ability, but it appears you need to spend more time studying the material before getting to that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, the first is that when your script runs, there are no elements for it to find, so you need to wait for the document to load using something like `window.onload = function() { /* ... */ }`.  The second is the `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` (essentially an array of nodes).  You have to get the one that you want, or else the method `appendChild` won't exist (since the `HTMLCollection` has no such method).  Also, `createElement` takes the name of the element, in this case `p`, and then you can use `setInnerHTML` to set the contents.

Your code should look something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
     var input = document.createElement("p");
     input.innerHTML = 'Hello';
     var container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
     container[0].appendChild(input);
};
```

Comment: If your script is simply moved to just before the closing `body` tag, there won't be a need to set up a `load` event handler (and, in this case, it should be a DOMContentLoaded event handler for a better UI). Also, `innerHTML` shouldn't be used when the content doesn't contain any HTML, use `textContent` instead. Lastly, `getElementsByClassName()` probably shouldn't be used at all here because it returns a "live" node list, which is very expensive in the first place, but makes no sense when you only want one element. `querySelector()` is better here.